# Distributed Transaction from Multiple Sources to a Single SQL server Instance

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

What I want to do is have multiple threads, processes or even machines share a single transaction. To be precise. I want to share out a chunk of work (mostly SQL Server queries) to my multiple threads, processes or machines, and I want the work to be atomic. I have looked at MSDTC, but it seems to be great if you want to, for example, update several different SQL Server instances (or other resources), and have everything under the same transaction, but it seems to always originate from the same source. i.e. one process (one connection). Is it possible? No restriction on technology, except SQL Server. I want two phase commit, but I want to start the transaction from one machine, and give that transaction (or a way to join it) to other processes.

**Problem Definition**
The problem is I have a long process, which involves some complicated calculations and updates to the database. The whole process can be scheduled and a lot of it can be processed in parallel. I'd like to farm that processing (including database updates) to separate processes including remote processes.

Answer (score 3):

To answer strictly the question:

- You start a transaction and call [`sp_getbindtoken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180061.aspx) from first session
- You join the transaction with [`sp_bindsession`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174403.aspx) from other sessions

However this is almost certainly **not** what you want to do. I recommend you describe the *actual problem* you're trying to solve, not asking how to implement a specific solution you believe is appropiate.

Comment: " a lot of it can be processed in parallel" There is absolutely no way a transaction can execute multiple statements in parallel (binding session into a single transaction makes no difference). Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx

Comment: It's not the actual SQL statements I want to execute in parallel. It's the processing prior to the SQL statements. One thing I have looked at is to pass the SQL statements through a single process. It doesn't matter if they are processed linearly.

Comment: If you want to scale out the processing, why do you ask about enlisting in transactions? Do all DB interaction in on process/session and hand over the work (via IPC) to your processes. Btw, if the processing is so heavy as to worth scale out then by definition it cannot be done in a single transaction, due to transaction length constraints. Seems like what you really want is a Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a big transaction; like loading a huge row-set by a select statement; If I'm in a right way; I hope this steps will direct you to what you want ;).

1. Each process, thread or machine say them stations needs a unique ID, like s1, s2, ..., sn.
2. [Optional] As capacity of each station set a station size for all.
3. Store this data in a table like `station`.
4. Now with a [dynamic] paging solutions using from `station` table.
5. Assign each page to a station, call stations to execute their pages.

**Example:**

Query:

```
select * from someTables
```

stations:

```
stationId | size   
----------+----------
s1        | 10
s2        | 20
...       | ...
----------+----------
          | sumSize
```

(i.) You need a queue that repeated when `sumSize` is less than `count(*)`

> `queue_repeat_count = (select count(*) from sometables) / sumSize`

When you call stations you need to repeat it `queue_repeat_count` times.

In each queue you have a `cursor` on `station` table to call station with an argument, like this:

> station_Calls(queue_repeat)

You have a stored-procedure in your server that handles paging with queue_repeat argument.

This is just an idea in my mind, I hope it can help you ;).